# Login to a windows (domain) user account when not connected to internet

Tags: windows, domain, user

When I am on my local network I log into a computer that is added to a domain. This creates a local user profile with my documents, desktop etc. Problem is that I am unable to login to this account when not connected to internet. Is there some way to override this or do I need to have two accounts - one local and one for a domain?

thank you

Comment: To be clear your sat at your computer, your computer is part of a domain and you leave the network and you can no longer log in? or is it something else?

Comment: Where is your Domain Controller located? Is it LAN (as in the same building) or is it a remote server only accessible over a WAN (in this case the Internet)?

Answer (score 9):

It is a policy that is set on the domain controller, called GPO(Group Policy Object). Anyone with enough authorization has the ability to set the number of cached credentials(0-50), by changing GPO. If that number is set to 0, then it will only allow logons when connected to the DC. You cant login to your domain account in that case.

If you want to confirm if this is indeed the case, you can check the number of cached logons in Local Security Policy:
Start>> type **local security policy** and enter>> Security Settings>> Local Policies>>Security Options>>Interactive Logon:Number of previous logons to cache

If that number is set to 0 then it is indeed the case. Even if you change that number the GPO will override it. Bottom line is the Organisational Units's(OU's) GPO has the final say in local policies, *by default* (which can be changed by authorized users ). In this case, you will have to contact your system-administrator.

For more details on processing  policies:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779964%28v%3dws.10%29#how-and-when-group-policy-is-applied

For more details on who can change GPO:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787798%28v%3dws.10%29

Answer (score 0):

If the computer you're adding the user to is a windows 10 machine, here's what worked for me:

establish a VPN connection via an VPN/RRAS server to your domain thru whatever means necessary.
The two options i found most suitable (in order of easiest to hardest)

1. create a VPN connection thru the DUN connections area in control panel. while connected to the VPN add the user account thru any local admin or privelege delegated user account.
   1a. log out of that user account, at the sign in screen check the lower right hand corner for the WIFI/AP icon, click it and find/connect to your VPN/DUN connection.
   1b. Once connected to your VPN login to your newly added domain user account.

2.if you're using a prefab vpn server setup like OpenVPN or other such VPN w/ GUI, connect to the user account with the VPN connection and establish connection to domain.
2a. while still logged into that user account, press CTRL+ALT+DEL and bring up the options menu and select "SWITCH USER"
2b. after pressing switch user, you will be taken to the login screen where you can connect to your newly added domain user account.

Credentials cache on first login and a vpn login may not be necessary for subsequent logins.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you're after a 'roaming' profile rather than the standard you have.

Comment: It has nothing to do eith roaming or standard user profiles, it is to do with whether the user login credentials are cached for offline use or not.

Comment: My 'answer' is in simple laymans terms lol

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with that in simple laymans terms either ;-) A standard profile is stored on the machine a roaming profile is stored on the server. Best for this OP is a standard (local) profile and cached credentials.

Comment: While this is appears to be a legitimate *attempt* to answer the question, it's a wrong answer. Even if it were correct, it doesn't explain *how* to use a roaming profile, making it an unhelpful post.